# Check if dict has entry when mock is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

One of my classes needs to do something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, someDict, someOtherObject):
        self._someDict = someDict
        self._someOtherObject = someOtherObject

    def func(self):
       self._someDict["key"] = None
       self._someOtherObject.foo()
```

Now, I would like to check if `"key"` exists inside the passed dictionary at the moment, foo was called.

```
class Test( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_funcShouldAddKeyToDictionaryBeforeCallingFoo(self):
        objectMock = Mock()
        someDict = {}
        aUnderTest = A(someDict, objectMock)

        aUnderTest.func()

        # assert "key" in someDict when called objectMock.foo()
```

How can I check if the dictionary already has an entry before foo was called?

Comment: Where does `_someObject` property come from?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thank you for pointing that out. It was a mistake. Should be `_someOtherObject`

Comment: `assert "key" in a._someDict`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen But what if "key" was added to the dictionary after calling foo. The test will pass although I do not want it to pass. My aim is to recognize if the dictionary entry was added before I called foo(), not just if it was added.

Comment: Ah, sorry - obviously didn't read your question correctly. Got it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `foo` with your own function that does the check:

```py
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_funcShouldAddKeyToDictionaryBeforeCallingFoo(self):
        def check_dict():
            self.assertIn("key", someDict)

        objectMock = Mock()
        someDict = {}
        aUnderTest = A(someDict, objectMock)
        objectMock.foo = check_dict  # "check_dict" will be called instead of "foo"
        aUnderTest.func()
```

This way your check is done at the moment `foo` would have been called in the tested code, as needed.